# Any way around dispatch pattern with no control over referenced classes

Tags: java

I need to operate on an object of uncertain type, I know which types it can assume but I have no control over these types. I cannot modify the Classes A, B, ..

Is there a better solution than:

```
if (obj instanceof A)
        return extractA((A) obj);
if (obj instanceof B)
        return extractB((B) obj);
....
```

thanks!

Comment: Are there different `extractStuff` methods defined for each type then?

Comment: Nope not really.

Comment: Then what is your intention? How do you expect `extractStuff` to work (or in other words what do you expect to pass?)

Comment: @user7 bruh i not mawillec

Comment: @Rob Oh. Didn't notice that. Thought it was a response for my question

Comment: @user7 because I dont believe there is a better way than isinstance()

Comment: I am overloading `extractStuff(A a)`, `extractStuff(B b)`, ..
so that I can work with methods pertaining to the object
`a.getMessage()`... and such

Comment: I see. You cannot then delegate to the right `extractStuff` based on the type at runtime as this (picking the overloaded method) has to happen at compile time

Comment: @user7 oh no and thanks

Comment: can any of your referenced classes be super/sub class of another referenced class?

Comment: @diginoise no, they are all on the same hierarchical level

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, you cannot delegate to the right overloaded `extractStuff` because the overloaded method to be invoked has to be decided at compile time.

I'm suggesting an option here to reduce the clutter in the code with all the `if.. else` by replacing it with a predefined mapping.

Assuming `obj` has a base type, you can define the which overloaded `extractStuff` to be invoked for each subclass of the type of `obj`.

```
Map<Class<? extends Number>, Function<Number, String>> mappings = new HashMap<>();
mappings.put(Integer.class, i -> extractStuff((Integer) i));
mappings.put(Float.class, f -> extractStuff((Float) f));
mappings.put(Long.class, l -> extractStuff((Long) l));
```

Here, `Number` is the base type and we have `extractStuff` for some of the subtypes of `Number`.

```
private static String extractStuff(Integer obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
    return "Integer called";
}
private static String extractStuff(Float obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
    return "Float called";
}
private static String extractStuff(Long obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
    return "Long called";
}
```

Now, we can delegate to the right `extractStuff` by looking up the `mappings` by passing the *class* of the runtime object we get

```
public static void test(Number n) {
    System.out.println(mappings.get(n.getClass()).apply(n));
}
```

Calling code

```
test(1);
test(1f);
test(1L);
```

This prints

```
1
Integer called
1.0
Float called
1
Long called
```

You need to handle the missing mappings.
Example: `test(new BigDecimal(1));`

**EDIT**:
Thanks to Bubletan@ for suggesting this

When you encounter a missing mapping, you can loop till you find one by traversing up the inheritance hierarchy

```
for (Class<?> c = n.getClass(); c != Object.class; c = c.getSuperclass()) { 
   //process and break once you found an entry in the map
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Base Type? The objects implement Serializable, but I can't work with that type and other than that don't extend anything other than Object.
edit: I think I am clear about base type now

Comment: Ok. I meant the type that is common (sort of Least common ancestor) to all the types you handle in `extractStuff`. Worst case it'll be Object.

Comment: If your classes may have subclasses, you have to do a loop `for (Class<?> c = n.getClass(); c != Object.class; c = c.getSuperclass()) { ... }` and call `mappings.get(c)` until you find something.

Comment: @Bubletan That could be one way to do it. I already mentioned that this has to be dealt with. I have updated the answer with your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you already overload methods `extract(A a)`, `extract(B b)` then you don't have to detect the type by using `instanceof` and casting. Method dispatch in Java will do just that.

Just create a utility class (here `TypeFacade`) with overloaded methods for all supported types, e.g.

```
public class ClassCaster {

  public static class A {
    public String getName() {
        return "A";
    }
  }

  public static class B {
    public String getMyName() {
        return "b";
    }
  }

  public static class C {
    public String getClassName() {
        return "C";
    }
  }

  public static class TypeFacade {

    public static String extractName(A a) {
        return a.getName();
    }

    public static String extractName(B b) {
        return b.getMyName();
    }

    public static String extractName(C c) {
        return c.getClassName();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(TypeFacade.extractName(new A()));
    System.out.println(TypeFacade.extractName(new B()));
    System.out.println(TypeFacade.extractName(new C()));
  }
}
```